# Alexa lambda function defaulting to unhandled?

Tags: aws-lambda, launch, alexa-skills-kit, unhandled-exception

Below is my code for my Alexa lambda function with all my data and other intents removed. The problem I'm having is that my lambda function doesn't seem to launching and I'm constantly getting the output, "sorry, I don't know what to" meaning that it's going to the unhandled function. Could anyone please advise?

```
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.353021cb-577e-4cfc-9edd-b440e6f095fe';

var handlers = {
   'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit(':tell', 'I can help you pick your tie. Tell me the color of your outfit, pattern of your shirt, or pattern of your tie.','Tell me the color of your outfit, pattern of your shirt, or pattern of your tie.');

    },
'Unhandled': function() {
    this.emit(':tell','Sorry, I don\'t know what to do');

    },
    };

exports.handler = function(event,context){
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event,context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you test your Skill? If you tested it using the ('old') Service Simulator, you don't get a request of the `LaunchRequest` type, but an `IntentRequest` with the best-matching intent of your interaction model - Just as when you invoke your Skill with an intent such as 'Alexa, ask tie picker to pick a tie'.

If you want such 'deep' invocations to trigger your first handler, you could replace `LaunchRequest` by `NewSession`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @kd1996: Glad I could help! Feel free to accept the answer if it resolved your issue. :)